# Merge 2 SpatiaLite layers into one

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I have a SpatiaLite database with some multipolygon layers loaded.

What I would like to do is to merge (not dissolve) 2 layers into 1. 
Both layers have the same SRID and same field name (they are a result of the same algorithm).

I'm looking for a SpatiaLite funcion that does the same thing of QGIS -> Union.

Is there a simple comand to do that?

---

My solution, using @Alexandre's suggestions:

```
CREATE TABLE merged AS
SELECT * FROM layer1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM layer2;

SELECT RecoverGeometryColumn('merged', 'Geometry',  32632, 'MULTIPOLYGON', 'XY');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use DB Manager, you can use plain SQL to union two tables. Something like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM my_table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT field1, field2 FROM my_table_2
```

Notice that the fields must match in both tables in terms of data type, but they do not need to have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

for show geometry in Qgis Canvas you need call a colum named geometry

for the example:

```
SELECT field1, field2, geometry FROM my_table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT field1, field2, geometry FROM my_table_2
```

with geometry colum qgis can show on screen